# Change numbers in object with many arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, game-physics

I have a fields object with multiple one dimensional arrays written in JavaScript. I want to be able to change numbers in the object, by clicking a button or whatever. One way is, that i create a complete new object, with just that change. But i don't want to create every time a complete new one.

So how is it possible to change the 11 in the middle of the row to any other number? I need this change for my tilemap.

```
var fields = [
[2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,5,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0],
[7,7,3,7,7,7,7,7,0,7,7,7,4,7,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0],
[2,2,2,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,1,2,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,2,2,2,2,0,0],
[7,7,2,2,0,0,7,7,11,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], // this row i want change the 11
[7,7,7,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,7,7,0,7,7,7,7,3,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,7,0,0,0,0,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,1,2,2,2],
[2,1,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,2,0,0,0,0,0], 

]
```

Comment: You can access the nested arrays with `fields[nestedArrayIndex][secondLevelIndex]`.  You can also change the value by assigning a new value to that

Comment: If it always is the same structure, use `fields[8][8]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fields = [
[2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,5,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0],
[7,7,3,7,7,7,7,7,0,7,7,7,4,7,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0],
[2,2,2,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,1,2,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,2,2,2,2,0,0],
[7,7,2,2,0,0,7,7,11,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], // this row i want change the 11
[7,7,7,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,7,7,0,7,7,7,7,3,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,7,0,0,0,0,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,1,2,2,2],
[2,1,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,2,0,0,0,0,0], 
];

function changethe11(){
  fields[8][8] = 32;
  console.log(fields);
}
```

```html
<button onclick=changethe11()>change the 11</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a multidimensional array with as many fors as dimensions your array has.

```
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < fields[i].length; j++){
        if(fields[i][j] == 11){
            fields[i][j] = "THE VALUE YOU WANT";
        }
    }
}
```

You can acces any position you want, if you don't know the keys from your array, if you do know them you can do like:

```
fields[row][column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bitshifting by one bit to right, which divides the value by two and returns an integer number for the middle index.

**DEMO**

```js
var fields = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0],
    [7, 1, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 5, 7, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 7, 7, 11, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 2, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 3, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

  ],
  row = fields.length >> 1,
  
  result = fields[row],
  
  col = result.length >> 1;

fields[row][col] = 34

console.log(fields)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a function like this on the array and give it the parameters for the number you want to change (num) and the number you want to change it to (newNum)

```js
var fields = [
[2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,5,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0],
[7,7,3,7,7,7,7,7,0,7,7,7,4,7,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0],
[2,2,2,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,1,2,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,2,2,2,2,0,0],
[7,7,2,2,0,0,7,7,11,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], // this row i want change the 11
[7,7,7,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0],
[7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,7,7,0,7,7,7,7,3,7,7,2,2,2,2],
[2,7,0,0,0,0,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,1,2,2,2],
[2,1,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,2,0,0,0,0,0], 

]

function swapValues(num, newNum) {
  fields = fields.map(val => val.map(v => v === num ? newNum : v))
}
swapValues(11, 9)
console.log(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can born if you want to change also other numbers or all the 11 in the array...The code down, loop every array and find the number you want to replace in this case 11 and after give a new value 15, but it do it with all 11 in the multidimensional array....Otherwise others answred you to replace only that position.If you want to replace for example all 7 with another number change the value, numberToReplace = 7 and v[i] = new value and so on....But you can also amplify it and for example you can change all the 7 in the second array ot fourth array just adding an if i==8 in this case the 8th array as 11 but you can replace all the 7 in i=2 and so on....Bye

```
                var fields = [[2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
                [7,1,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,3,5,7,0],
                [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0],
                [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,0,0,0],
                [7,7,3,7,7,7,7,7,0,7,7,7,4,7,0,0,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,0],
                [2,2,2,0,0,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,2,2,2,2],
                [2,1,2,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,0,2,2,2,2,0,0],
                [7,7,2,2,0,0,7,7,11,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], // this row i want change the 11
                [7,7,7,2,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0],
                [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
                [0,0,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2],
                [0,0,0,7,7,0,7,7,7,7,3,7,7,2,2,2,2],
                [2,7,0,0,0,0,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,1,2,2,2],
                [2,1,7,7,7,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,0,0],
                [2,2,2,2,7,0,7,7,7,7,7,2,2,0,0,0,0],
                [2,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,2,0,0,0,0,0]];

                $.each(fields,function(k,v){
                  //console.log(fields[k]);
                  $.each(v,function(i,j){
                    //console.log(j);
                    numberToReplace = 11;
                    if (j==numberToReplace){
                         v[i]=15;//<--New value 15
                        }
                        });
                     });
                console.log(fields);
```